# Specifying level-3 random intercept in R

Tags: r, lme4, multi-level, random-effects

I am using the `lmer()` function (`lme4` package) in R for analysing a longitudinal study in which I measured 120 subjects, 6 times. In first instance, I specified a model like this:

```
library(lme4)
model1 = lmer(DV ~ 1 + X1*X2  + (1+X1|SubjectID), REML="false")
```

`X1` is a time-varying variable (level-1) and `X2` is a subject-level variable (level-2).

Because these subjects are nested within several teams, I was advised to include a random intercept at the team-level (level-3). However, I only find how to include both random intercept and slope:

```
model2 = lmer(DV ~ 1 + X1*X2  + (1+X1|TeamID/SubjectID), REML="false")
```

Does anyone know how to add only a level-3 random intercept to model 1?

Comment: So is `X1` the timepoint? What's a "subject level variable"? Maybe you could give a sample of your data.

Comment: X1 is a level-1 variable that has a different value every wave/timepoint (there are 6 timepoints). In other words, its value changes over time. X2 is a level-2 variable, which has the same value during all waves. So, each subject has a value of X2 that remains constant over time. It is actually a very basic multi-level model I guess? Is this clear enough? @Joe

Comment: So it sounds like you are looking for random intercepts only for `TeamID` and `SubjectID`. If this is the case you only need `(1|TeamID) + (1|SubjectID)`.

Comment: Okay I think I got it than. Thanks! So when I want a random intercept and random slope for SubjectID but only a random intercept for TeamID it would be (1+X1|SubjectID) + (1|TeamID)?

Comment: Exactly. You're saying "expect differing baselines only for `TeamID` but differing baselines and different responses to `X1` for `SujectID`". Does that clear up the matter?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. I've added it more clearly as an answer. Would you be so kind as to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the term `(1|SubjectID)` you're telling the model to expect differing baselines only for different instances of `SubjectID`. To tell the model to expect different responses of this to the fixed effect `X1`, we use `(1+X1|SubjectID)`. Therefore, you just need the terms

```
(1|TeamID) + (1+X1|SubjectID)
```

in your model.

By the way there's plenty of good information about this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).